# Фильтр по 2 словам в Excel

Tags: excel, filter

Есть 2 файла с большим количеством данных. Один из столбцов содержит данные, состоящие из одного слова либо из двух. Как бытро отфильтровать этот столбец, чтоб остались только данные из двух слов?

Comment: По значению функции - ненулевой позиции пробела в тримованной строке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вкладка *Данные*, установить *Автофильтр*.

*Автофильтр-Текстовые_фильтры-Содержит*(вписать пробел)-*ОК*

' --------------

Часто данные содержат лишние пробелы слева или справа от текста. В этом случае в отдельный столбец вписать формулу, которая очистит данные:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(A2)
```

где *A2* - ссылка на ячейку с текстом.

Протянуть формулу по строкам. Фильтровать по столбцу с формулой.

' --------------

Фильтрация макросом.

```
Sub Filter_Row()
Dim a()
Dim rRng As Range
Dim lRws As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' выключаем обновление экрана

    With ActiveSheet
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' последняя заполненная ячейка столбца A
        If lRws < 2 Then Exit Sub ' нет данных, выходим
        a = .Range("A1:A" & lRws).Value ' данные столбца в массив

        .Rows("2:" & lRws).Hidden = True ' скрываем все сроки
        Set rRng = .Cells(1, 1) ' формируем диапазон отображаемых строк

        For i = 2 To lRws ' цикл по данным
            If Trim(a(i, 1)) Like "* *" Then ' если есть пробел
                Set rRng = Union(rRng, .Cells(i, 1)) ' пополняем диапазон
            End If
        Next i

        rRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False ' показываем строки
    End With

    Set rRng = Nothing ' освобождаем память
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' включаем обновление экрана
End Sub
```

' --------------

Можно копировать данные и показать их в отдельном диапазоне:

```
Sub Filter_Two()
Dim r()
Dim lRws As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' последняя заполненная ячейка столбца A
        If lRws < 2 Then Exit Sub ' нет данных, выходим (в первой строке "шапка" таблицы)
        r = .Range("A1:A" & lRws).Value ' данные столбца в массив

        For i = 2 To lRws ' цикл по данным
            If UBound(Split(Trim(a(i, 1)), " ")) = 1 Then ' другой вариант определения пробела
                k = k + 1: r(k, 1) = r(i, 1) ' перезаписываем данные в массив
            End If
        Next i

        .Range("G2").Resize(k, 1).Value = r ' выгрузка в столбец G
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Благодарю. Это очень помогло.